# Pass variables PHP Smarty to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

In our webpage, we need to access to a PHP variable inside a javascript code. Specifically, we need to pass a parameter that is a URL defined by a PHP variable called $link_es

I've tried doing this

```
var r_obj = {
"Company": { "CompanyId": xxxxxx },
"RatingboxId": xxxxx,
"ProductCode": encodeURIComponent($link_es),
```

where $link_es is the URL stored in a variable that we need to pass as parameter.

How could I pass that parameter? That is, how could I convert a PHP variable into a Javascript one? Thank you.

PD: I'm using Smarty PHP so there could be some problems there.

Comment: Any of the comments below seem to be working, possibly because I'm using Smarty template

Comment: The code is inside a .js file, a smarty template, a php file?

Comment: A smarty template, that is, a tpl file

Answer (score 1):

If the script is inside a tpl file, it's as easy as assigning it to a javascript variable:

```
<script>
var link_es = '{$link_es}';
//do whatever you want with it
alert(link_es);    
</script>
```

make sure that the javascript code isn't between {literal} tags, though

Comment: What to do if the javascript code is within `{literal}` ? I am facing same problem.

Comment: just define the variable before the literal block or close the literal block with {/literal}, define the variable and then open {literal} again. Also, if you're using smarty 3 you probably don't even need to use literal, as long as every opening bracket ("{") in the javascript code has a space after it.

Comment: This code will not work for object structures.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a pre defined javascript variable whose value is set by PHP

```
<script>
var link_es = "<?php echo $link_es ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"ProductCode": encodeURIComponent(<?= $link_es ?>)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use something like this in your PHP file:

```
<script>
var myVar = <?php echo $link_es; ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you can work as follow:

Add following code in your PHP file

```
<script>
     var jsVariable = <?php echo $phpVariable ?>;
</script>
```

And in js file can simply access to variable as follow:

```
console.log(jsVariable);
```

If you want to pass an array first should json_encode that like follow:

```
<script>
     var jsVariable = <?php echo json_encode($phpVariable) ?>;
</script>
```

in this case you have an object in javascript which and trace that with console.log

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1** If you writing your javascript on Php page then you can use pass it like

```
"ProductCode": encodeURIComponent('<?= $link_es ?>'),
```

**Case 2** if you have separate javascript file then you have to define global variable in your php file then you can access this in your js file.

```
<script>
     var jsVariable = <?php echo json_encode($link_es) ?>;
</script>
```

**In Case 2, I personally used to store this value in hidden field with some id then i use it in js file**

```
<input type="hidden" id="link_es" value="<?= $link_es ?>" />

//then in js file access like this

"ProductCode": encodeURIComponent($("#link_es").val()),
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself have finally found a solution. It consists of the following:

First of all, we include a div tag like the below

```
<div id='linkespanol' style="display: none;">
{$link_es}
</div>
```

Later on, inside the script, we can access to the full URL like that

```
var a = window.location.href.split("/")[0];
var b = window.location.href.split("/")[2];
var c = a+"//"+b;
var linkidioma = c+document.getElementById('linkespanol').textContent.trim();
```

Variable $link_es doesn't contain full URL, but /es/productCode.html so in order to generate full URL I use window.location.href to get what I want from the current URL and finally concatenate both. I use trim to get rid of some blank spaces.

It's possibly a quite bad solution but works. Possibly, without using Smarty, there could be a simpler way.

Comment: You're overcomplicating it, please look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this `<?php echo $link_es; ?>` That will echo out the variable into the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

None of the suggested answers helped, I ended up doing this.

```
var data= JSON.parse('{$data|@json_encode|@addslashes}');
```

Comment: `var data = {$data|@json_encode};`.

Comment: What if you have quotes inside the variable?

Comment: So what? `json_encode` produces a *valid Javascript literal*. You don't need to put that into a string and then parse that string. If you don't, then you also don't need to worry about quotes.